# Remove section number = 0 in the header

Tags: header-footer

I have section numbers and section titles in my header. I want to remove the section number before the table of contents. While the section number = 0. 
And keep it in the rest of my document.

Does anyone have a good suggestion for this problem?

I also wonder if it's possible to write the subsection number in the header?

My main-file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\input{packages.tex}

\begin{document}

\large
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

Preface + abstract ++

\tableofcontents    
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

Text..........

\setcounter{table}{0}

Apendix....

\end{document}
```

My packages-file:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[nynorsk]{babel}

    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}

    \fancyhf{}      

    \rhead{\fancyplain{}{"Title"}} 
    \lhead{\fancyplain{}{\rightmark }} % 1. sectionname, 1.1 subsection name etc
    \cfoot{\fancyplain{}{\thepage}}
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you want, but try: \renewcommand\thetable{\arabic{table}} in your preamble

Comment: I did not understood before... I thought you want to remove \thesection from the \thetable ... looking for new answer

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Can you reduce your code the parts are relevant to the question.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for help as to make a usable subset of your code.

Comment: In my preface (before table of contens) I have no section numbering (or page numbering). I have header with section number, section title and document title. The problem is that I don't want the section number to show up, while it's equal to zero. (In the preface.)

Comment: In my header '0 Preface' is left aligned and the title 'Master thesis' are right aligned.

Answer (score 4):

In `article`, `\sectionmark` should do `\markboth`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nynorsk]{babel}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{blindtext} % just for the example

\fancyhf{}      
\fancyhead[R]{``Title''}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}} % 1. sectionname, 1.1 subsection name etc
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{frontmatter}{%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyhead[R]{``Title''}%
  \fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}%
}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  \markboth{\ifnum\value{section}=0 \else\thesection\ \fi #1}{}%
}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{frontmatter}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\section{Preface}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\section{Abstract}
\blindtext

\clearpage
\tableofcontents    

\clearpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\blinddocument

\setcounter{table}{0}

Appendix....

\end{document}
```

Avoid `\pagenumbering{gobble}`; if you need to use `hyperref`, add `\pagenumbering{Alph}` after `\pagestyle{frontmatter}`.

[image]

Comment: Impressive screenshot :)